# Android - Calling a method in a Fragment when the Activity container is launched from homescreen

Tags: android, android-fragments

Basically I have a social media app which main content needs to be updated whenever user restarts the app from home, or from system tray. I would like to implement it only on home start for now.

Tried using this :

```
if(RUN_ONCE){
            bottomLobiFragment = new BottomLobiFragment();
            replaceFragment(bottomLobiFragment, utilities.lobbyTag);
            activeLobi = (BottomLobiFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.activity_newsfeed_frame);
//            activeLobi = (BottomLobiFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(utilities.lobbyTag);
            activeLobi.refreshNewPost();
            RUN_ONCE = false;
        }
```

to check whether the activity is ran first time or not. `RUN_ONCE` is a static variable. But `activeLobi` always returns `null`, either using `findFragmentById` or `Tag`, so I seem to be unable to use this approach..

Is there any other way of determining when the activity is launched from home or tray, and access the method of the Fragment which either is active or had just been added to the Activity?

`replaceFragment()` method :

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag){
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.replace(R.id.activity_newsfeed_frame, fragment, tag);
    ft.addToBackstack(tag);
    manager.executePendingTransactions();
    fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: if you are replacing `bottomLobiFragment` then why don't you use this instance only `bottomLobiFragment.refreshNewPost();`

Comment: Oh you're right about that, in the block I posted I can use the instance itself, but I use that block of code somwhere else too.. Or should I just make a new instance of `lobi` everytime other fragment should be replaced by `lobi`?

Comment: Wait.. I can't use the same instance `bottomLobiFragment.refreshNewPost();`, it hasn't been started yet, it's still all null.. Weird..

Comment: no.. make fragment instance global

Comment: show `replaceFragment()` method code.. .its null thats so weird

Comment: I think NPE is inside `refreshNewPost()` method. can you post the error log.

Comment: Yes it is there, because after running `replaceFragment()`, it directly goes to the next line in `if(RUN_ONCE)` which is `activeLobi.refreshNewPost();` without running `onCreateView` in the `Fragment`